# Definir a col do bootstrap-vue conforme a resolução

Tags: javascript, vue.js

em um código Vue tenho a seguinte b-col

```
<b-col class="card-image-top col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
```

O último item deve ser col-xl-3 caso a resolução seja menor que 1400px e col-xs-4 caso seja menor que 1400px. Como seria esse if verificando a resolução via js?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: acredito que os col-* seja referente ao sistema de grids do bootstrap, da uma olhada na documentação para entender como funciona.... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Isso, é sim Bootstrap, nisso preciso que em um momento imprima um, em outro imprima outro =)

Answer (score 0):

Tente realizar desta forma:

```
<b-col :class="window.screen.availWidth < 1400 ? 'card-image-top col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3' : 'card-image-top col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-4'">
```

Quando você coloca : na frente está dizendo para o VueJS que o que virá entre as aspas é um código javascript. Então pode criar uma condição, nesse caso é um if ternário que verifica se é menor que 1400 e retorna a primeira sentença entre apóstrofos ('') e se der false retorna a sentença que vem após os :